# Drools Flow Human Task example: How do I prevent 'Named query not found' exception being thrown?

Tags: java, drools-flow

I'm trying to follow the [Drools Flow](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-flow.html) example code in the [Human Task documentation](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.0.1.26597.FINAL/drools-flow/html_single/index.html#ch.Human_Tasks) and I have the following code:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.drools.task.service.TaskService;

// ...

EntityManagerFactory emf = 
  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.drools.task");
TaskService taskService = new TaskService(emf, null);
```

I have put a `persistence.xml` file in `META-INF` as specified [here](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.0.1.26597.FINAL/drools-flow/html_single/index.html#d0e2079) (which is definitely getting picked up as I get an XML parsing error if I mangle it) but the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Named query not found: UnescalatedDeadlines
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(
  AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:108)
at org.drools.task.service.TaskService.<init>(TaskService.java:65)
at org.drools.task.service.TaskService.<init>(TaskService.java:48)
at com.sample.RuleFlowTest.main(RuleFlowTest.java:32)`
```

Note that the second parameter to `TaskService` is required but not mentioned in [the documentation](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.0.1.26597.FINAL/drools-flow/html_single/index.html#d0e2079). It seems unlikely to me but could it be that setting it to `null` as I've done is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prevented this exception by copying both `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` from `drools-process-task-5.0.1.jar/META-INF` (the UnescalatedDeadlines named query being specified in `orm.xml`) into my built `META-INF` directory.

However, I'm now getting another exception (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/ANTLRException` from Hibernate)...

To fix the `antlr/ANTLRException` problem I downloaded the latest Hibernate distribution (`hibernate-distribution-3.3.2.GA-dist.zip`) and added `antlr-2.7.6.jar` from the `lib` directory to the classpath.

Does it need to be this complicated?